# How to ignore function _interopRequireDefault in istanbul coverage report?

Tags: javascript, browserify, babeljs, istanbul, karma-coverage

Babel compiles my modules to include the following line:

```
function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { 
    return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; 
}
```

Which, to my best understanding, is to [deal with CommonJS imports](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/babel-commonjs.html).

How can I ignore this line from being covered in my coverage report? My branch coverage is usually affected by this line.

I wasn't able to add an inline ignore comment such as `/* istanbul ignore next */`, because I can't add it directly over this line. Adding the comment to the beginning of the file adds it before the class definition.

I also tried using Babel's [auxiliaryCommentBefore](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) option to add a comment before compiled lines, but it adds it almost everywhere in the code, so this can't be used.

Is there a way to ignore this line when analyzing the coverage?

Comment: do you use grunt / gulp / whatever?

Comment: @smnbbrv we use Gulp with Browserify. The testing framework we use is Jasmine.

Comment: we use a replace plugin to simply replace just these lines in grunt with ones with `/* istanbul ignore next */`. Define a proper pattern and it works quite nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using [isparta](https://github.com/douglasduteil/isparta) in order for the coverage to use the ES6 code before the transpiling, which is actually more accurate (we wanted to check coverage against the code we actually wrote, not the code that's compiled). Thanks for the help. :)